# how do I a delete with a query and filter in solr 4 (w/ solarium)

Tags: solr, solarium

I'm using Solarium with Solr 4 and I need to delete with multiple criteria.  The docs show how to delete with a query

```
$client = new Solarium\Client($config);

$update = $client->createUpdate();

$update->addDeleteQuery('type:comment');
$update->addCommit();

$result = $client->update($update);
```

This works fine. But if I need a different criteria, eg writer_id:123, I'm not sure what to do.  If I add another addDeleteQuery line the final raw query looks like:

```
<update>

  <delete>
    <query>type:comment</query>
  </delete>

  <delete>
    <query>writer_id:123</query>
  </delete>

  <commit/>

</update>
```

It seems this will delete them independently.  I'm not sure if it matters but the defaultOperator from the schema is AND.  Looks like from http://www.solarium-project.org/forums/topic/change-operator/ that it's not easily overridable yet.  I'm not sure how to apply the solution there to delete, if that would work even work here.

How can I delete items in solr using multiple criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Clubbing it into a single query `<delete><query>type:comment AND writer_id:123</query></delete>`

Comment: almost - change the OR to an AND I'll mark this as answered. I did it as addDeleteQuery('(type:comment AND writer_id:123)') and that seemed to work.  I'm not sure if the () are needed in the query.

Comment: remeber using double quote in post.jar, not single quote otherwise you'll get an queer error message: "Should not have < at this time...".

Comment: Is it also possible to delete documents filtered by "fq"? Use Case: Delete all documents with a certain empty field. As far as I know those can only be found via "fq=-myfield:[* TO *]"...

Comment: How about delete documents whose type is comment and writer_id is **not** 123?

Answer (score 0):

Note update your solrconfig.xml file to allow document deletion via Solr Query, by setting the enableStreamBody to true in your requestParsers configuration under requestDispatchers with the following

```
<requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true"
                    **enableStreamBody="true"**
                    multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000"
                    formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048"
                    addHttpRequestToContext="false"/>
```